# To find most recent value of date column in SQL Server for a list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I have about 1500 tables in my database. I used Information Schema to list all tables and all columns in each of these tables.

I would like to find out the most recent value of the columns

```
Select Table_name, Column_name
From DB.Information_Schema.Columns
```

This returns this output:

```
Table_name| Column_name
----------+------------
A         | C1
A         | C2
A         | C3
```

All 1500 tables were displayed.

I now want to get a third column which gives me the most recent value (i.e the most latest value) of every column

```
Table_name | Column_name| Column_Value
-----------+------------+--------------
A          |  C1        |  V1 
A          |  C2        |  V2
```

Comment: First, how do you determine the "most recent value"?  Second, this will require dynamic SQL of some sort.

Comment: This is much more complicated that you may think. To start with, you need a column in each table to identify the most recent record. Then, you would need dynamic SQL to build the query (since the tables to query are only know at runtime). And even so, you still need to convert the datatypes so everything can fit in a single column.

Comment: Maybe it could be easier that for each table you create some kind of trigger for the inserts so that for each new insert in a table, this insert is also updated to an other table that contains the latest values for each column?

Comment: I think the best idea is using trigger to fill a table with three column(Table_name ,Column_name,Column_Value) and each trigger first delete the last values that related to this table, then fill this table for selec top(1) of inserted table of trigger

Comment: Depending on your licensing, CDC might what you're looking for instead of triggers. But honestly, as Gordon said, you first have to determine "what is the most recent value", what king of database (oltp, warehouse, ... ?)  and the table structure,specially if you have common system column of your model

Comment: Are all of the columns listed in `Column_name` of type `date` and you need the max value of each (as the title of your question suggests)? This implies that all tables only have date columns though...

Comment: Hey Christian. thank you. there are lot more columns other than date column in each table. but all the tables, do have a date column. "Date " is the column for which I want recent values from each table. NOTE: date column name is not same in all tables